# Run through transaction data, delete rows if they are near another row in time

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have a series of transactions in a PostGres database (Greenplum to be specific) with date_ids like:

```
+----+-----------+----------------+
| id | date_id   | desired result |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 |        58 | keep           |
|  2 |        99 | discard        |
|  3 |       110 | keep           |
|  4 |       188 | keep           |
|  5 |       190 | discard        |
|  6 |       191 | discard        |
|  7 |       201 | discard        |
|  8 |       244 | keep           |
|  9 |       255 | discard        |
+----+-----------+----------------+
```

Date_id is just a stand-in for dates (so date_ids 58 and 59 would be consecutive days; the first two transactions in the above table are 39 days apart).

I am trying to implement the following rule: For the first transaction, keep it -- but discard any other transactions within 50 days.  After 50 days, keep the next transaction.  Then discard any other transactions within 50 days.  Etc.  As a result, no two remaining (not discarded) transactions are within 50 days of each other.

In this instance, transaction id=1 is a "keep" because it's first.  Transaction id=2 is discarded (within 50 days of the first transaction).  But transaction id=3 is "keep" despite being only 11 days after the second transaction.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement this? I thought this would be possible to do by simply joining the table to itself but I cannot figure out a way that satisfies these rules.

This does not help:

```
with intervals_between_transactions as 
(select t1.id transaction_id
, t1.date_id date_of_transaction
, max(t2.date_id) date_of_previous_transaction
from transactions t1
join transactions t2 on t2.date_id < t1.date_id
group by 1)
select *
from intervals_between_transactions 
where date_of_transaction - date_of_previous_transaction > 50
```

because this discards transaction 3 despite it being a "keep".

This also does not work:

```
select date_id::numeric / 50.0 fifty_day_window
, min(id)
from transactions group by 1
```

Because it would 'keep' both transactions id=8 and id=9 despite them only being 11 days apart.

Thank you!

Comment: Since this is basically an iteration, I'd be looking at using a recursive CTE

Answer (score 0):

Like Craig suggested, this can be solved with an iteration using a CTE, but you need several levels of nesting to make it work:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN (
  WITH RECURSIVE min_date AS (
    SELECT min(date_id) FROM mytable
  ), keep AS (
    SELECT id, date_id
    FROM mytable, min_date
    WHERE date_id = min_date.min
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT m.id, m.date_id
      FROM mytable m, keep
      WHERE m.date_id - keep.date_id > 50
      ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1
    ) sub
  )
  SELECT id FROM keep);
```

The recursive part of the CTE has many restrictions, such as no aggregate functions, no `ORDER BY` and no `LIMIT 1`, either of which would have been nice to add just the one next record to the result set. Wrapping the recursive term in a sub-query, however, will allow the use of `ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1`, hence the additional nesting.

As with any `DELETE`statement, first verify that the correct records are deleted by running just the CTE. See [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b25c8/22/0) here.

Comment: FYI, "with recursive" is not supported by Greenplum

Answer (score 0):

If you have 50 days, I assume your task is not global, i.e. you've got another fields and the full question is like "keep only 1 transaction for each 50 days for each customer". This way the easiest way in my opinion would be to group both transactions and their dates into two arrays and write a function that would process list of transactions and dates implementing your logic

As it is already said, it is an iterative logic. Knowing that transaction X has 5 transactions before it within 50 days could not allow you to make a decision whether this transaction should be kept or not. Each decision to keep depends on the previous decision. So you have to either follow my advice and group transactions into arrays and process them in function, or write a pl/pgsql function that would iterate over the table row-by-row filtering the data. I'm afraied these are the only options for Greenplum